# Reverse order of a XML Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

In a SQL Server table, I have a `XML` column where status are happened (first is oldest, last current status).

I have to write a stored procedure that returns the statuses: newest first, oldest last.

This is what I wrote:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDeliveryStatus]
    @invoiceID nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @xml xml 
    SET @xml = (SELECT statusXML
                FROM Purchase
                WHERE invoiceID = @invoiceID )

    SELECT 
        t.n.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as DeliveryStatus
    FROM
        @xml.nodes('/statuses/status') as t(n)
    ORDER BY 
        DeliveryStatus DESC
END
```

Example of value in the `statusXML` column:

```
<statuses>
    <status>A</status>
    <status>B</status>
    <status>A</status>
    <status>B</status>
    <status>C</status>
</statuses>
```

I want the procedure to return:

```
C
B
A
B
A
```

with `ORDER BY .... DESC` it return ALPHABETIC reversed (`C B B A A`)

How should I correct my procedure ?

Comment: You need to have something more than just the `status` value - some date&time, some consecutively increasing `ID` or something like that which you can then apply the `ORDER BY :... DESC` to ...

Comment: I agree, I also suggested to add at least date of the status change, but I'm not the owner of the DB. Any way Inverting the implicit order of XML is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to declare a variable first. You can (and you should!) read the needed values from your table column directly. Best was an **inline table valued function** (rather than a SP just to *read* something...)

- Better performance
- inlineable
- You can query many InvoiceIDs at once
- set-based

Try this (I drop the mock-table at the end - carefull with real data!):

```
CREATE TABLE Purchase(ID INT IDENTITY,statusXML XML, InvocieID INT, OtherValues VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES('<statuses>
    <status>A</status>
    <status>B</status>
    <status>A</status>
    <status>B</status>
    <status>C</status>
</statuses>',100,'Other values of your row');
GO

WITH NumberedStatus AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,InvocieID
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr
          ,stat.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS [Status]
          ,OtherValues
    FROM Purchase
    CROSS APPLY statusXML.nodes('/statuses/status') AS A(stat)
    WHERE InvocieID=100
)
SELECT *
FROM NumberedStatus
ORDER BY Nr DESC
GO
--Clean-Up
--DROP TABLE Purchase;
```

The result

```
+---+-----+---+---+--------------------------+
| 1 | 100 | 5 | C | Other values of your row |
+---+-----+---+---+--------------------------+
| 1 | 100 | 4 | B | Other values of your row |
+---+-----+---+---+--------------------------+
| 1 | 100 | 3 | A | Other values of your row |
+---+-----+---+---+--------------------------+
| 1 | 100 | 2 | B | Other values of your row |
+---+-----+---+---+--------------------------+
| 1 | 100 | 1 | A | Other values of your row |
+---+-----+---+---+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence for the nodes based on the existing order then reverse it.

```
WITH [x] AS (
   SELECT 
        t.n.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as DeliveryStatus
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.n.value('..', 'NVARCHAR(100)')) AS [Order]
    FROM
        @xml.nodes('/statuses/status') as t(n)
)
    SELECT  
        DeliveryStatus
    FROM [x]
    ORDER BY [x].[Order] DESC
```

... results ...

```
DeliveryStatus
C
B
A
B
A
```

Comment: It was easier to use `(SELECT NULL)` in your `OVER(ORDER BY...)`... The implicit order of XML allows this fastest approach... And no need for `.value('text()[1]','...')`, a simple `.value('.','...')` was enough...